# How to add property value from one array of objects into another (for the matching objects) in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

I am trying to filter array of objects based on another array of objects and after finding all matching items I want to set property and value from the first array object into corresponding object in the second array:

```
 const searchedProducts = products.filter(product =>
        uniqueProducts.some(
          uniqueProduct =>
            product.productId === uniqueProduct.productId,
        ),
      )
```

After here I need to set product.productName for each unique product object under productName property.

Ho such a thing can be achieved in a better way?

Comment: Please provide example input, and expected output.

Comment: @pilchard I just need to get uniqueProducts updated where new property productName will be available and set from products array of objects

Comment: In the future I would recommend providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that answering is not guess work, or extra work.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably most straightforward using `reduce()` combined with `find()` to both retrieve and verify that the second array contains each object.

```js
const uniqueProducts = [
  {id: 3, from: 'uniqueProducts', name: 'Unique 1'},
  {id: 12, from: 'uniqueProducts', name: 'Unique 12'}
];

const products = [
  {id: 1, from: 'products',  name: 'Product 1'},
  {id: 2, from: 'products', name: 'Product 2'},
  {id: 9, from: 'products', name: 'Product 9'},
  {id: 12, from: 'products', name: 'Product 12'},
];

const output = products.reduce((a, p) => {
  const uP = uniqueProducts.find(u => u.id === p.id);
  if (uP) a.push({...p, name: uP.name});
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have inventory where I have to add a **price property** and take its value from products array so I did this,

```
inventory = [
    {
        "productId": 1,
        "quantity": 100,
        "name": "2 Yolks Noodles",
        "image": "twoeggnoodles.jpg",
    }
]

Products = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "quantity": 100,
        "name": "2 Yolks Noodles",
        "image": "twoeggnoodles.jpg",
        "price": 34.95
    }
]


let product:any = [];
products.map((prod:any)=>{
    const index:any = inventory.find((u:any) => u.productId === prod.id);
    // console.log("item", index, '-', prod)
    if(index){
      product.push({...index, price: prod.price});
    } 
      return prod
  })
});
```